# How to find the node values in the Gaussian type quadrature formula?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I am trying to determine the node values in the Gaussian type quadrature formula given by:

[image]

How do I find node values for the Gaussian quadrature when the weight function is $ w(x) =\frac {1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} $ (Chebyshev Gauss)?

I know that the quadrature nodes $\phi_i$ are the roots of an orthogonal polynomial.

Would the method of unknown coefficients work in this case?

---

I am reading [here](https://etheses.bham.ac.uk/id/eprint/1352/1/Iqbal_10_MPhil.pdf), on Page 12 that the node values are the roots of the Legendre family of polynomials.

Since $L_3 = x^3 - \frac{3x}{5}$, the roots are $x=0$ and $x = \pm \sqrt {\frac{3}{5}}$

This doesn't seem to make sense because the roots are not all within the specified integral range of $\int_{-1}^0$

Comment: Gauss-Chebyshev has weight $w(x)=1/\sqrt{1\color{red}{-}x^2}$. Are you sure the weight function given is the right one?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, that was a typo from my end. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some partial results: we want to work out moments
$$\begin{align}M_k&=\int_{-1}^0\frac{x^k}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=(-1)^k\int_0^1\frac{x^k}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx\\
&=\frac{(-1)^k}2\cdot2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^k\theta\,d\theta=\frac{(-1)^k}2\text{B}\left(\frac{k+1}2,\frac12\right)\end{align}$$
Where $\text{B}(u,v)$ is the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). So for even $k$,
$$M_k=\frac{\pi k!}{2^{k+1}\left[\left(\frac k2\right)!\right]^2}$$
While for odd $k$,
$$M_k=\frac{-2^k\left(\frac{k-1}2\right)!\left(\frac{k+1}2\right)!}{(k+1)!}$$
Table for the first few $k$:
$$\begin{array}{c|c}k&M_k\\
\hline
0&\frac{\pi}2\\
1&-1\\
2&\frac{\pi}4\\
3&-\frac23\\
4&\frac{3\pi}{16}\\
5&-\frac8{15}\end{array}$$
We need a cubic polynomial $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ orthogonal to $x^k$ for $k\in{0,1,2}$. This gives us $3$ equations in $3$ unknowns:
$$\begin{array}{rrrr}\frac{\pi}4a&-b&+\frac{\pi}2c&=\frac23\\
-\frac23a&+\frac{\pi}4b&-c&=-\frac{3\pi}{16}\\
\frac{3\pi}{16}a&-\frac23b&+\frac{\pi}4c&=\frac8{15}\end{array}$$
It would be nice to represent $a$, $b$, and $c$ as rational functions of $\pi$, but numerically I get
$$\begin{align}a&=1.614477692\\
b&=0.702011721\\
c&=0.064088878\end{align}$$
**EDIT**: WolframAlpha spits out
$$\begin{align}a&=\frac{2\left(256-27\pi^2\right)}{5\pi\left(88-9\pi^2\right)}\\
b&=-\frac{3\left(-448+45\pi^2\right)}{20\left(-88+9\pi^2\right)}\\
c&=-\frac{2048-207\pi^2}{30\pi\left(88-9\pi^2\right)}\end{align}$$
So the cubic equation is
$$x^3+1.614477692x^2+0.702011721x+0.064088878=0$$
Roots are
$$x\in\{-0.123876429,-0.94052274,-0.550078523\}$$
We want to be exact for $k\in\{0,1,2\}$:
$$\begin{array}{rrrr}A_1&+A_2&+A_3&=\frac{\pi}2\\
x_1A_1&+x_2A_2&+x_3A_3&=-1\\
x_1^2A_1&+x_2^2A_2&+x_3^2A_3&=\frac{\pi}4\end{array}$$
I get
$$\begin{align}A_1&=0.308760976\\
A_2&=0.685202238\\
A_3&=0.576833113
\end{align}$$
I checked that
$$\sum_{j=1}^3A_jx_j^k=M_k$$
For $k\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ to the accuracy provided by Excel, so the formula is Gaussian.

For Legendre polynomials, the weight function is $w(x)=1$ and the interval is $(-1,1)$, neither of which matches the statement of your problem.

Comment: Thank you, this helps. Regarding the first half of the answer, why don't you use the normal basis $A_0, A_1, A_2 -> x^0, x^1, x^2$ ? This is what is usually done in the method of undetermined coefficients.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say here. I think perhaps you mean
$$\int_{-1}^0\frac{x^j}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=A_1x_1^j+A_2x_2^j+A_3x_3^j$$
Exact for $j\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and then solve the $6$ nonlinear equations in $6$ unknowns as suggested in the discussion around eq. $(2.11)$ of [the reference you provided](https://etheses.bham.ac.uk/id/eprint/1352/1/Iqbal_10_MPhil.pdf)? That would be really hard...

Comment: ...Instead I am using a $2$-step approach: the first step is to find the orthogonal polynomial $p_3(x)$ via equations $(2.18)$ of your reference and then to find its roots $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ as in Theorem $1$. Then I applied the equations at the top of my previous comment for $j\in\{0,1,2\}$, now $3$ linear equations in $3$ unknowns.