# How to find the weight coefficients in the Gaussian type quadrature formula?

Tags: numerical-methods

I am trying to determine the node values in the Gaussian type quadrature formula given by:

[image]

I need to find the weight coefficients for the Gaussian quadrature when the weight function is $ w(x) =\frac {1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} $

---

In order to do so, I use the Gram-Schmidt process on the standard  polynomial basis to get a second degree orthogoanl polynomial. The roots of this polynomial are the nodes.

I get -0.877 and -0.242 as the nodes which are within the integral range of -1 to 0.

How can I proceed from here to find the wieght coefficients?

Searching online I found this formula from Atkinson's '[An Introduction to Numerical Analysis](http://www.math.science.cmu.ac.th/docs/qNA2556/ref_na/Katkinson.pdf)'

[image]

During the calculation here, obne of the weight coefficients returns negative, which is impossible. I am therefore confused as to what I am doing wrong and if this is the right way to proceed. Any suggestoins are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of amusing that this problem is copied from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3493875/316404) only the upper bound of the summation has been changed by hand, forgetting to change the subscript on $R_3(f)$. Did you complain to your instructor for not having properly composed his problem in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)? In [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3493931/316404) I worked out a table of moments
$$M_k=\int_{-1}^0\frac{x^k}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$
$$\begin{array}{c|c}k&M_k\\
\hline
0&\frac{\pi}2\\
1&-1\\
2&\frac{\pi}4\\
3&-\frac23\\
4&\frac{3\pi}{16}\\
5&-\frac8{15}\end{array}$$
We need a polynomial $\varphi_2(x)=x^2+ux+v$ orthogonal to $x^k$ for $k\in\{0,1\}$. These leads to the $2$ equations in $2$ unknowns
$$\begin{array}{rrr}-u&\frac{\pi}2v&=-\frac{\pi}4\\
\frac{\pi}4u&-v&=\frac23\end{array}$$
With solutions
$$\begin{align}u&=\frac{2\pi}{3\pi^2-24}\\
v&=\frac{32-3\pi^2}{6\pi^2-48}\end{align}$$
Numerically,
$$\begin{align}u&=1.12023436678521858941728667302911065\\
v&=0.213163347581147484467276859105524958\end{align}$$
We can solve via the quadratic formula to get
$$\begin{align}x_1&=-0.877241625135156835342909006193109829\\
x_2&=-0.242992741650061754074377666836000821\end{align}$$
Now, in my previous answer I applied the formula to $x^k$ for $k\in\{0,1\}$ to get
$$\begin{array}{rrr}A_1&+A_2&=\frac{\pi}2\\
x_1A_1&+x_2A_2&=-1\end{array}$$
With solutions
$$\begin{align}A_1&=0.974866349911031438041049989239156851\\
A_2&=0.595929976883865181190271702400594548\end{align}$$
And we could check that the integration formula was exact for $f(x)=x^k$ for $k\in\{0,1,2,3\}$.

So now we want to apply formula $5.3.11$ from [Atkinson](http://www.math.science.cmu.ac.th/docs/qNA2556/ref_na/Katkinson.pdf) p. 272. We will need $a_2=\frac{A_3}{A_2}$ which is $1$ because we are using monic polynomials. Then we need
$$\begin{align}\gamma_2&=\int_{-1}^0\frac{\left(\varphi_2(x)\right)^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx\\
&=\int_{-1}^0\frac{x^4+2ux^3+(u^2+2v)x^2+2uvx+v^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx\\
&=M_4+2uM_3+(u^2+2v)M_2+2uvM_1+v^2M_0\\
&=0.00964381305182564583436743261678388874\end{align}$$
Fortunately in my previous answer I worked out
$$\varphi_3(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$$
Where
$$\begin{align}a&=\frac{2\left(256-27\pi^2\right)}{5\pi\left(88-9\pi^2\right)}\\
b&=-\frac{3\left(-448+45\pi^2\right)}{20\left(-88+9\pi^2\right)}\\
c&=-\frac{2048-207\pi^2}{30\pi\left(88-9\pi^2\right)}\end{align}$$
Numerically,
$$\begin{align}a&=1.61447769167994311356947744905749821\\
b&=0.702011720837368702218533133421594847\\
c&=0.0640888776572757287520840004030105744\end{align}$$
So now we can apply the formula from Atkinson
$$A_k=\frac{-a_2\gamma_2}{\varphi_2^{\prime}(x_k)\varphi_3(x+k)}$$
To get
$$\begin{align}A_1&=0.974866349911031438041049989239165999\\
A_2&=0.595929976883865181190271702400598399\end{align}$$
Wikipedia seems to have [a nicer formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature#General_formula_for_the_weights)
$$A_k=\frac{a_{n-1}\gamma_{n-1}}{\varphi_n^{\prime}(x_k)\varphi_{n-1}(x_k)}=\frac{a_1\gamma_1}{\varphi_2^{\prime}(x_k)\varphi_1(x_k)}$$
Again because we are working in monic polynomials, $a_1=A_2/A_1=1$ and if we let $\varphi_1(x)=x+w$ then the condition of orthogonality to $f(x)=1$ is $-1+\frac{\pi}2w=0$ so
$$w=\frac2{\pi}=0.636619772367581343075535053490057474$$
and then
$$\begin{align}\gamma_1&=\int_{-1}^0\frac{\left(\varphi_1(x)\right)^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx\\
&=\int_{-1}^0\frac{x^2+2wx+w^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx\\
&=M_2+2wM_1+w^2M_0\\
&=0.148778391029866966540125792329818225\end{align}$$
And now Wikipedia producees
$$\begin{align}A_1&=0.974866349911031438041049989239157236\\
A_2&=0.595929976883865181190271702400594740\end{align}$$
All of these results are consistent to IEEE-$754$ quadruple precision. Wikipedia's formula was a little nicer than Atkinson's in that it used the lower degree polynomial $\varphi_{n-1}(x)$ rather than $\varphi_{n+1}(x)$.